# AWS Amplify mock in HTTPS

Tags: https, mocking, backend, aws-amplify

Using the following stack:

- AWS amplify
- NodeJS
- ReactJS (built using create-react-app)

When running amplify mock it automatically assigns an endpoint with HTTP (as can be seen in the terminal and the `aws-exports.js` file).

I am however hosting my app locally in an HTTPS environment using `($env:HTTPS="true") -and (npm start)` so as to better accommodate the social sign-ins which usually require all requests to come from HTTPS even if on localhost.

I constantly have to change my env to HTTP to try out things with the mock backend instead of just maintaining everything in HTTPS.

Is there a way to let the mock backend be served over HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a partial answer.

using the chrome browser settings, select privacy and security and go to site settings.

Add the URLS you are requesting over http into the insecure content allowable section. This allows an origin of https to request over http.

Comment: This was a big help. Thanks. To clarify, if your app is running at https://localhost:3000/, and your graphQL server is at: http://192.168.86.20:20002, add `localhost:3000` to Settings > Privacy and security > Site Settings > Additional content settings > Insecure content > Allowed to show insecure content. Then your Local app will be able to use non secure URLs.